# Using htaccess deny causes error with PHP getimagesize

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following in my htaccess file to prevent access to a website outside of our network:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from xx.xxx.xxx.xx
</Limit>
```

But this causes the following error:

> `Warning:
>   getimagesize(http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/nalogo.png)
>   [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
>   /html/wp-content/themes/test/framework/styles.php on line 60`

Any ideas on how I can fix this? **This works if I disable that htaccess deny.**

Comment: without the htaccess directive, it works?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: Have you tried `getimagesize('local/path/to/uploads.../nalogo.png')` ?

Comment: Remove `GET` from `limit` to make it `<Limit POST PUT>`

Comment: I need to deny GET as I don't want anyone to access the website outside of the network. Basically I need to allow PHP to access things but not users...

Comment: @LozCheroneツ I can't change the path as it comes from a database (although I edited the path in the DB table, to test it and no that doesn't work either).

Comment: I didn't mean that to be answer to your problem, I just want to check what exactly is causing this problem.

Comment: @anubhava doing that WOULD allow access and stop the error. But I already know that :)

Comment: Well you know that but we don't since you didn't mention anywhere in your question :)

Comment: Says that at the bottom of my question in bold :) about how disabling the deny fixes it, but I can't because I need it. That all been said... any ideas on getting around this?

Comment: Disabling the `deny` is different from just taking out `GET` as it narrows down the problem to `GET` method only.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding localhost in the allow list:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from xx.xxx.xxx.xx
 allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
```